# Induced norm problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

For any matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ prove:

$$\|A\|_{p, i}:=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}=\sup _{\|u\|_p=1}\|A u\|_p.$$

I found on the internet that

$$\|Au\|_{p, i} \leq \|A\|_{p, i}\|u\|_{p}$$

Can someone explain me why this property holds?

But isn't $$\|A\|_{p, i}:=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}$$ by definition of induced norm?

What should I prove there?

Also then
$$\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}=\sup _{\|u\|_p=1}\|A u\|_p.$$

We have

$$\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A \frac{u}{\| u\|_p}\|_p}{\|\frac{u}{\| u\|_p}\|_p}=\sup _{u = 1} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking why the equality between the $u\neq 0$ and $\|u\|=1$ suprema holds? Or are you asking why the submultiplicativity inequality $\|Au\|\leq \|A\|\|u\|$ holds?

Comment: Norm of a bounded map $A: X\mapsto Y$ is given by $||A|| = \sup\limits_{||x||\leq 1} ||Ax||$. So if you map is bounded than a unit sphere ($||x||\leq 1$) is carried over to some bounded set and then we can talk about $\sup$ of that set. If the bounded map is linear than we can write $||A|| = \sup\limits_{x\neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$, or $||A|| = \sup\limits_{||x||= 1}||Ax||$.

Comment: Both @whpowell96

Comment: Still not sure how to nicely write the proof @WeißeKatze

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. For any matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ prove:

$$\|A\|_{p, i}:=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}=\sup _{\|u\|_p=1}\|A u\|_p.$$

Note that for any nonzero vector $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists some $v$ such that $u = \|u\|v$, where $\|v\| = 1$. Therefore, we have $$\|A\|_{p, i}:=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p} =\sup _{\|v\|=1} \frac{\|A (\|u\|v)\|_p}{\|(\|u\|v)\|_p} = \sup _{\|v\|=1} \frac{\|A v\|_p}{\|v\|_p} = \sup _{\|v\|=1}\|Av\|_p.~\blacksquare$$

#### 2. Show that

$$\|Au\|_{p, i} \leq \|A\|_{p, i}\|u\|_{p}.$$

Notice that for $u=0$, the result is trivially true. Now consider $u\neq 0$. Recall that $\|A\|_{p, i}:=\sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p}$. Then for
$$\|A_{p,i}\| = \sup _{u \neq 0} \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p} \geq \frac{\|A u\|_p}{\|u\|_p} \implies \|A u\|_p \leq \|A_{p,i}\|\|u\|_p.~\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $||Ax||\leq ||A|| \text{ }||x||$ note that for $x\neq0$ you can write

$\frac{||Ax||}{||x||} = ||A\frac{x}{||x||}|| = ||Az||\leq ||A||$, where $z$ is a normalized vector, whose norm is 1. Therefore, the last inequality follows from the definition $||A||=\sup\{||Ax||: ||x||=1\}$.